# How does the steps parameter relate to size of samples in tf.contrib.learn?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The canned estimators in 1.0 (LinearClassifier, DNNClassifier, etc..) use the [Trainable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Trainable) interface which defines:

```
fit(
    x=None,
    y=None,
    input_fn=None,
    steps=None,
    batch_size=None,
    monitors=None,
    max_steps=None
)
```

and describes steps as

> Number of steps for which to train model. If None, train forever. 'steps' works incrementally. If you call two times fit(steps=10) then training occurs in total 20 steps. If you don't want to have incremental behaviour please set max_steps instead. If set, max_steps must be None.

I'm at a loss for what this means exactly.

```
m = LinearClassifier(
    feature_columns=[sparse_column_a, sparse_feature_a_x_sparse_feature_b],
    optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
      learning_rate=0.1,
      l1_regularization_strength=0.001
    )) 

m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=???)
```

Using a LinearClassifier, how do we train on a single pass of `train_input_fn`? Should steps be the number of samples in `train_input_fn`?

What if we want to train on each sample in `train_input_fn` 3 times?

**Answer 1 (was removed?): "Steps is number of times input_fn is called for data generation"**

I think a lot of the logic for this question is in Estimator's `_train_model` [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L941)

It executes the following:

```
all_hooks = []
self._graph = ops.Graph()
with self._graph.as_default() as g, g.device(self._device_fn):
  random_seed.set_random_seed(self._config.tf_random_seed)
  global_step = contrib_framework.create_global_step(g)
  features, labels = input_fn()
  .......
  .......
  with monitored_session.MonitoredTrainingSession(
      ...
      hooks=all_hooks + model_fn_ops.training_hooks,
      chief_only_hooks=chief_hooks + model_fn_ops.training_chief_hooks,
      ...
  ) as mon_sess:
    loss = None
    while not mon_sess.should_stop():
      _, loss = mon_sess.run([model_fn_ops.train_op, model_fn_ops.loss])
```

`input_fn` is called only once, and then for each step, 
`mon_sess.run([model_fn_ops.train_op, model_fn_ops.loss])` is run

This suggests `input_fn` is not called for each `step`. Also, empirically, I tried an input function like

```
def train_input_fn():
    current_log = TRAIN_FILES.pop()
    with open('./logs/' + str(random.random()) + "__" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + "__" +  str(time.time()) + ".run", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(("Ran log file %s" % (current_log)).encode('utf-8'))
```

and for steps > 1 there is still only one log file written.

Comment: I think that's irrelevant. The question is: how do we train 3 times? Also if you are going to down vote a question please spend the time to understand it. If anything above is unclear please point that out.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the documentation for [Trainable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Trainable) (which you also linked), and specifically comparing `steps` to `max_steps`, it looks like the difference is that:

> Two calls to `fit(steps=100)` means 200 training iterations. On the
>   other hand, two calls to `fit(max_steps=100)` means that the second call
>   will not do any iteration since first call did all 100 steps.

So I think you would use `steps` if you are running `fit` inside of a loop, every iteration of which you are doing something that changes the input and target data going to your `fit` function, e.g. loading new data from files on disk. In pseudo-code:

```py
def input_fn():
    """Get features and labels in batches."""
    new_features = get_new_features()
    new_labels = get_new_labels()
    return new_features, new_labels

for _ in range(num_iterations):
    m.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=num_steps)  # runs num_steps times on current data set
```

This would generate new training data with every outer loop iteration, and run on that training dataset for `num_steps`. Ultimately you would probably set this up to work its way iteratively through the whole dataset once and then maybe wrap the loop here in another loop to run multiple epochs. If you are giving it all the training data at once, however, then you would use `max_steps` instead. Again, in pseudocode.

```py
def input_fn():
    """Get ALL features and labels."""
    all_features = get_all_features()
    all_labels = get_all_labels()
    return all_features, all_labels

for _ in range(num_epochs):
    m.fit(input_fn=input_fn, max_steps=num_max_steps)  # runs num_max_steps times on full dataset
```

Here in a single iteration of the loop you would work your way through the whole dataset (probably using the `batch_size` argument of `fit` to control batch sizes), and then each iteration of your loop is another epoch through the whole dataset.

Either way, it makes sense for `input_fn` to only be called once for a single call to `fit`, as `input_fn` is just providing the data on which `fit` will operate for this iteration of whatever loop it is called from.

Comment: so you would say that _steps=1_ fits the model on all data in `input_fn`? I wonder why in the TF examples/tutorials they always pick _steps=5000_ or similar. In this case, that would be equivalent to 5000 epochs, right?

Comment: It seems that using `steps` will fit that many iterations on whatever data is provided by one call to your `input_fn`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> Using a LinearClassifier, how do we train on a single pass of
>   train_input_fn? Should steps be the number of samples in
>   train_input_fn?

input_fn should return a tuple of: *features* (tensor or dictionary of tensors) and *labels* (tensor or dictionary of tensors). These features and labels will construct a mini-batch to run computations on.

Simplest input_fn could look like:

```
def input_fn():
    value_a = tf.constant([0.0])
    features = {'a': value_a}

    label = tf.constant([1.0])
    return features, labels
```

When m.fit() is called, it calls _input_fn_ to construct feeding part of the graph. Then m.fit() creates a session, runs initialisers, starts queue_runners, etc. and calls session.run(...) *steps* times or until certain exception is thrown.

So if you want to train on a single pass of input_fn output you can just do:

```
m.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1)
```

If you want to change number of samples in the mini-batch, you need to change input_fn to return more samples and labels for them.

> What if we want to train on each sample in train_input_fn 3 times?

There are couple of options:

1. If you use input_fn with tf.constants, you can do m.fit() multiple times
2. If you use readers and queues (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data), you can specify _num_epochs_, which is number of times the data will be fed.

In tensorflow 1.1, there are a helper function (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs) to create input_fn, for feeding numpy arrays and pandas data frames to the graph. For both of them you can specify _num_epochs_.